# event bubbling advantages vs. event capturing advantages

Tags: javascript, event-bubbling

I ran into a discussion about "event bubbling" as described here. I don't completely understand this.

http://catcode.com/domcontent/events/capture.html

Can you say when do you use event bubbling and when do you use event capturing when manipulating DOM elements? When MUST you use event capturing vs. MUST you use event bubbling?

Comment: there are few musts in javascript, and i can't think of any in this situation. For 90% of JS events like clicking a button, no canceling involved,  it doesn't matter which method you use. Bubbling is the far more common one these days; going from most specific to least specific. With delegated and nested events, it might be slightly more efficient to use capturing, but since currentTarget is available anyway, it doesn't make or break anything...

Comment: There's no MUST, there's only what a specific circumstance requires.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: wouldn't "requires" be considered a synonym for "must" ? Can you describe a situation where capturing is preferable (i can't)?

Comment: @dandavis imagine that on your path home there's a huge bad guy (*other event handlers attached to a nasty element*), you'll go the other way around, right?

Answer (score 0):

Event bubbling is almost always used because it is convenient for most usages. You should almost always use event bubbling. Anyway, most events can only bubble. Also, old browsers such as IE8 and less do not support tunneling. Events only bubble in those versions.

[Here is a web site explaining to process](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing). However, in my experience, I've never had to rely on tunneling. It is why in most cases (if not all by default), the event handlers just ignore the tunneling part and only react on bubbling events.